# How to read Data and verify data from a Nfc card in flutter

Tags: flutter, nfc

I've been making an app in flutter that displays user details

```
FlutterNfcReader.onTagDiscovered().listen((onData) {
      Navigator.push(context,
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => username()),// new page that i want to navigate
      );
```

Answer (score 0):

With this fork from `flutter-nfc-reader` you can now read and write nfc tags from android and read them from ios https://github.com/semakers/flutter-nfc-reader

to install add the following dependency your `pubspec.yaml`

```
dependencies:
  flutter_nfc_reader:
    git:
      url: git: //github.com/semakers/flutter-nfc-reader.git
      ref: master
```